# Getting Actual Placement of a Flyout

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I have a flyout that appears near the cursor when a particular user input is triggered.

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308515.aspx#placing_a_flyout), the `Flyout.Placement` property is only a preference and does not necessarily reflect the position of the flyout.

I expect the framework to call [`GetFlyoutPlacement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.xamluipresenter.getflyoutplacement) to determine the actual placement.  I want to know what the actual placement is so that I can add a little arrow pointing at the cursor position, something like shown in the following:

[image: popup with pointer]

Is my only option to make the call to `GetFlyoutPlacement` myself (triggered on the `Flyout.Opening` event), or is there some more convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My calls on `GetFlyoutPlacement` and [`GetFlyoutPlacementTargetInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.xamluipresenter.getflyoutplacementtargetinfo.aspx) resulted in `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.` which didn't leave me very much to go on, so I just ended up implementing what I imagine is the logic behind those functions:

```
public static FlyoutPlacementMode GetActualFlyoutPlacement(
    Rect placementTarget,
    Size flyoutSize,
    FlyoutPlacementMode preferredPlacement )
{
    Rect ViewArea = Window.Current.Bounds;
    ViewArea.X = 0; // may have non-zero offset for multi-monitor setups
    ViewArea.Y = 0; // but we are only interested in offset relative to app view area

    switch (preferredPlacement)
    {
        case FlyoutPlacementMode.Right:
            if (desiredSize.Width < ViewArea.Width - placementTarget.Right) return FlyoutPlacementMode.Right;
            if (desiredSize.Width < placementTarget.Left) return FlyoutPlacementMode.Left;
            if (desiredSize.Height < placementTarget.Top) return FlyoutPlacementMode.Top;
            return FlyoutPlacementMode.Bottom;
        case FlyoutPlacementMode.Left:
            ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the approach I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40112955/7037690). I believe it is better, because instead of guessing the internal placement algorithm it just compares the absolute coordinates of the flyout and the target element.