# Winrt - Adjusting flyout according to where it appears

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, flyout

I have a `GridView` in a windows store project, that contains some big squares, and inside those i have a list of user images, when i tap on of those images a flyout appears on the right showing some information like this.

[image]

the problem is that my gridview extends to the edges of the screen and beyond, and when that does i get this situation, i press the user with the red border near the edge of the screen and flyout appears on left.

[image]

My flyout placement is set to Right, and im guessing since the element i press is near the edge it follows the Fall back order with according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308515.aspx) is Right > Left > Top > Bottom.

What i would like to know is how to detect this happens, so i can adjust my flyout position, or another viable alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

After searching through properties and Dependency properties on Flyout and FlyoutBase, I haven't found a way to simply get the actual placement of the Flyout (which is unfortunate because I think that can be important, as we see in your case). Perhaps you can try what was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609252/getting-actual-placement-of-a-flyout) by implementing a method that compares the desired size of the Flyout with the available space.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to FlyOut.Opened event and compare absolute coordinates of the flyout and the element you're showing it at. Here is an example for top/bottom flyout placement (easily extendable to check for left/right as well):

```
    private void FlyOut_Opened(object sender, object e)
    {
        GeneralTransform flyOutTransform = 
            flyOut.Content.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
        Point flyOutPosition = 
            flyOut.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

        GeneralTransform showAtElementTransform = 
            showAtElementTransform.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
        Point showAtElementPosition = 
            showAtElementPosition.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

        if(flyOutPosition.Y < showAtElementPosition.Y)
        {
            // top
        }
        else
        {
            // bottom
        }
    }
```